# Decimal on calculator app implementation method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on adding to my currently functioning app by adding a much needed decimal option to my standard calculator. I have struggled finding a way to do this. I finally came across a way to implement a decimal today. The problem is that I am getting errors so I can't build it to see if it works. Can somebody please tell me how to fix the error I'm having? Or a better way to implement a decimal?

Here is my code:

.h file:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  CalculatorPlus
//
//  Created by William Harris on 12/20/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 William Harris. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#import "Calculator.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"
#import "ViewController3.h"
#import "ViewController4.h"

@class ViewController;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate,   ADBannerViewDelegate> {

float result;
IBOutlet UILabel *calculatorScreen;
NSInteger currentOperation;
float currentNumber;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *calculatorScreen;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ADBannerView *ad1;
-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)cancelInput:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)cancelOperation:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)changeCalculatorTapped:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m file:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  CalculatorPlus
//
//  Created by William Harris on 12/20/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 William Harris. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

NSUInteger decimalPlacesLimit = 2;

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize ad1, calculatorScreen;

-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender {

currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (float) [sender tag];
calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f",currentNumber];
NSRange range = [self.calculatorScreen.text rangeOfString:@"."];

BOOL canUpdateScreen = YES;
if(range.location != NSNotFound) {
    if([sender tag] == 99) {
        // Already got dot, cannot show another dot
        canUpdateScreen = NO;
    } else {
        NSArray *explodedString = (NSArray*)[self.calculatorScreen.text     componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        if(explodedString[1].length >= decimalPlacesLimit) {
            canUpdateScreen = NO;
        }
    }
}

if(canUpdateScreen) {
    if([sender tag] == 99) {
        self.calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.calculatorScreen.text, @"."];
    } else {
        self.calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%ld", self.calculatorScreen.text, (long)[sender tag]];
    }
}
}

-(IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender {

if (currentOperation == 0) result = currentNumber;
else {

    switch (currentOperation) {
        case 1:
            result = result + currentNumber;
            break;
        case 2:
            result = result - currentNumber;
            break;
        case 3:
            result = result * currentNumber;
            break;
        case 4:
            result = result / currentNumber;
            break;
        case 5:
            currentOperation = 0;
            break;
    }
}
currentNumber = 0;
calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f",result];
if ([sender tag] == 0) result = 0;
currentOperation = [sender tag];
}
-(IBAction)cancelInput:(id)sender {

currentNumber = 0;
calculatorScreen.text = @"0";

}

-(IBAction)cancelOperation:(id)sender {

currentNumber = 0;
calculatorScreen.text = @"0";
currentOperation = 0;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

calculatorScreen.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
}

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Error message I'm getting:

[image: Error Message I'm Recieving]

Can somebody please tell me how I can fix the error? Or, if there is a better way to implement decimals? I really need help getting the decimal working. Thank you!

Comment: I rolled this back to the original question since it was closed as a duplicate. Instead of completely changing your question, post a new question.

Comment: That makes things more difficult, but I understand. I am going to post a new question, maybe you'd like to answer it? @rmaddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`explodedString` is a `NSArray *`. `NSArray`s store their objects as `id`s, which are basically just generic objects. Although you and I know that the contents of `explodedString` are `NSString *`s, the compiler doesn't. It takes the safe route of keeping all of the objects in the array as `id`s.

To summarize:
The compiler doesn't know that `explodedString[1]` is a string.

Fix: Explicitly cast `explodedString[1]` to `NSString *`.

```
if(((NSString *) explodedString[1]).length >= decimalPlacesLimit)
//      ^
//   Add this
```

Comment: that solved the error. Thank you, however, it didn't completely answer my question. I just ran my app and while the decimal worked, it didn't work with my preexisting calculator. As I asked in my original question, and now since this didn't work, what would I add to my functioning calculator to make decimals work with the preexisting functions and code. I am going to edit my question and add more screenshots to further help you to help me. Thank you!!!!

Comment: @iOSDeveloper You need to post a whole new question for your new issue. This question should just cover the error.

Comment: @rmaddy I adjusted the question to fit the more broad range of problems I am having in implementing this one specific idea

Comment: @iOSDeveloper As I said, post a new question. Don't completely change your question after people have posted answers based on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The objects in an NSArray are of type id (anonymous object.) You have to cast them to the desired type, or use bracket notation.

You could rewrite the offending line as

```
    if (((NSString*)explodedString[1]).length >= decimalPlacesLimit)
```

or

```
    if ([explodedString[1] length] >= decimalPlacesLimit)
```